# createPortal Property 'children' is missing in type but required in type 'ReactPortal'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to portal out an element to `document.body` but typescript claims

```
Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.
```

How can I fix this createPortal typing error?

[image]

It also does not work even with a native HTML element like `<p>` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code and reproduce it in ts playground?

Comment: Oh it's different in NextJS, nevermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createPortal` does not work in NextJS components

Comment: Please explain further? :)

Comment: Can't seem to find the source for this anymore, sorry. But I remember reading it somewhere